# Prolog Cut Query

Tags: prolog, prolog-cut

In Prolog using the cut. Why is the effect of the following query to return the following:

```
?- !,false.
no
```

yet this query returns the following:

```
?- !;false.
yes
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first query performs an AND on ! (which always returns yes) and false, which always returns no. yes AND no = no.

In the second query, the ! commits execution to the first branch, that is, !, which always returns yes.

Comment: `;` does not act the same as logical OR in the presence of `!`. For example `parent(X) :- !,false;father(X).` always returns `no`.

Comment: Of course, that makes perfect sense. I edited the answer accordingly, thanks!